# Animate div with jquery slide out

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a div to slide out of my view I am doing the following:

```
$this.stop().animate({"left":"0px", width:0}
```

The result is of the is that the div contains alot of text and it looks weird when the width is being shrunk to `width:0`. How can I change the width:0 to so it just moves the div to the left and doesn't shrink it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#targetDiv').animate({'width':'0'},2000);
```

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Anu3C/)

## EDIT:

if you want to move the child to the left, then the left of the child must be less than the left of the parent to the tune of width of child. okies, below is what i am speaking :

```
<div id="parentDiv" >    
    <div id="targetDiv" style="overflow:auto;height:20px;">
        this is lot of text
    </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
var target = $('#targetDiv');
var left = '-'+ target.width() +'px';
target.animate({'margin-left': left },2000);
```

see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Anu3C/5/)

you get the idea right? make it more neat

Comment: ofcourse it is shrinking the div, if you want to move it then you need to specify a negative left in comparison to the parent, there's no other way, wait, i will post an example

Comment: thanks! What should be negative in the parent??Do I need to animate the parent as well?

Comment: no you don't, you just have to make sure that the left of the child is lower than parent by the amount of width of it

Comment: I dont understand can you send me example?

Comment: Thanks! it working. Also, if I want it to go back to its originial place what should I do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48387/discussion-between-user1163234-and-manish-mishra)

Answer (score 0):

[[image]demo](http://jsbin.com/gawitifo/1/edit)

Simply create an inner `DIV` container with width set in CSS.
Than using jQuery animate the width of the desired parent.

```
$this.stop().animate({left:0, width:0});
```

you don't need `px`